# AWS API Gateway 403 Forbidden response OPTIONS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call API of AWS through JEE and I got this error in the Chrome Console

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
But when I call same API from postman or when I use it in localhost it works.

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your API Gateway OPTIONS method, go into Method Response and add a response header with the name 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

[image]

Now go into Integration Response, expand the default 200 response and in Header Mappings put the URL of your DNS. If you don't want to restrict by URL, just put a *.

[image]

You may need to add this configuration to other methods as well.

Comment: Thank Raul, strange I did this configuration but I still get the same error ...

Comment: When I did test yes It works for GET (I got response 200 and data), for OPTIONS (I got Response 200 with no data) .. the test failed when I try to call service in my angular project (postman works also well)

Comment: Have you deployed the new configuration? Is the error the same?

Comment: Yes, after to add configuration I deployed (API GATEWAY -> Resources -> Actions -> Deploy API) .. Yes the same when I use service throught my angular app .. but postman work well also the test inside ... in the console errot I got `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Dev/listJobs' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`    I have the same error

Comment: I have similar issue but not getting the above CORS error in console, just getting 403 Forbidden status in network tab without any response body. any help is appreciated.